# Select rows in a dataframe based on a condition spanning several dates

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with the dataframe below. I would like to apply a filter that will create a new dataframe of the filtered result set. The filtered dataset should result in a True condition if the first and last day of a three day rolling lookback window are less or equal to 0.5, **the middle value should be excluded**.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'DT':    ['2/20/2020', '2/19/2020', '2/18/2020', '2/17/2020','2/16/2020','2/15/2020','2/14/2020','2/13/2020','2/12/2020','2/11/2020'],
    'LSTPX': [0.5, 1.00, .44, 1.23, 1.56, 1.89, 0.46, 1.88, 0.49, 0.44, ],
})
```

Result Should equal

```
DT LSTPX

2/20/20 True

2/14/20  True
```

Answer (score 2):

I made use of the fact that the source DataFrame contains **consecutive**
dates in **descending** order.

So instead of the rolling window, *shift* can be used to
get *LSTPX* from the row 2 positions down from the current row:

```
result = df[(df.LSTPX <= 0.5) & (df.LSTPX.shift(-2) <= 0.5)]
```

The result is:

```
          DT  LSTPX
0  2/20/2020   0.50
6  2/14/2020   0.46
```

If you want *LSTPX* column of the result changed to *True*,
then:

- `result = result.copy()` - Create a copy of *result*,
  since for now it is a **view** of the original DataFrame, and any
  attempt to modify it would cause *SettingWithCopyWarning* message.
- `result.LSTPX = True` - Replace *LSTPX* with the new value.

If the condition concerning consecutive dates and / or sort
is not met, another approach is needed:

1. Create an auxiliary *Series* - *LSTPX* column indexed by *DT*:

   ```
   wrk = df.set_index('DT').LSTPX
   ```
2. Define a function to get a value from a *Series* (*s*)
   by index (*dd*), but if the passed index value is absent,
   return a default value:

   ```
   def getByIdx(s, dd, defVal):
       return s.loc[dd] if dd in s.index else defVal
   ```
3. Define a filtering function:

   ```
   def myFilter(row):
       return (row.LSTPX <= 0.5) and (getByIdx(wrk, row.DT - pd.Timedelta(2, 'd'), 1.0) <= 0.5)
   ```
4. Generate the result by application of this function:

   ```
   result = df[df.apply(myFilter, axis=1)]
   ```